# How to query multiple non related tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

Basically I have three tables and I want to select attributes from all 3.

```
SELECT Users.Name, Sales.SaleID, Return.ReturnAmount
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Sales ON Users.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
```

However, Return has a relationship with Sales, but not Users.

How would I include returnAmount?

Comment: Show the layout of the table, along with some sample data (by editing the question).

Comment: It's easy enough to `JOIN` the table. Simply add `JOIN Return ON 1=1`. However, if the table is not related, how would you determine exactly which values should be shown? In the worst case scenario, you end up with a Cartesian product returning all rows of the `Sales` and `Users` table (that have a valid `JOIN`, times the amount of rows in the `Return` table.

Comment: @SchmitzIT But return is related to sales such that Sales.SaleID = Return.SaleID, but return is not related to users

Comment: I wonder why the relationship between Users and Sales is on `SalesID` though: `ON Users.SaleID = Sales.SaleID` So, a sale has many users and every user is related to one sale? This doesn't look correct design.

Comment: @user2525364 - That makes sense. So you `JOIN` he `Return` table to the set using those criteria. A `JOIN` doesn't need to connect all tables (that'd be impossible), but rather you string together pieces of information that relate to part of the set.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said Return has a relationship with Sales following should work. Just check the column on which you need to join Return with Sales.

```
 SELECT Users.Name, Sales.SaleID, Return.ReturnAmount
 FROM Users
 INNER JOIN Sales 
   ON Users.SaleID = Sales.SaleID
 INNER JOIN Return
   ON Return.SaleID = Sales.SaleID -- You said Return has relationship with Sales.
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely query I can think of given these table names is:

```
SELECT u.Name, s.SaleID, r.ReturnAmount
FROM Users u INNER JOIN
     Sales s
     ON u.UserID = s.UserID INNER JOIN
     Returns r
     on r.SaleID = s.SaleID;
```

It would be a very unusual data layout that has a `SaleID` in the `Users` table.